# Proving that a conformal mapping preserves the real analyticity of function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading the lecture notes for my one of my physics courses on scattering theory and in it, I came across a statement that I really do not quite get. Basically we start with a function $f$ that is supposed to be real analytic so satisfies the condition
$$f(\bar{s}) = \overline{f(s)}$$
in the complex $s$-plane. Now because the function $f$ is conjectured to be analytic, we perform a series of conformal mappings that basically allow us to study certain properties of $f$ more easily. The conformal maps that are performed have the form -
$$x = \frac{s-a}{s+a},\quad y = x^2,\quad v= \frac{y-C}{y-B},\quad u = \sqrt{v},\quad z = - \frac{u-i\beta}{u+i\beta},$$
where $a$, $B$, $C$, and $\beta$ are positive real numbers. After performing these mappings, the text goes on to state "these mappings are such that they preserve the real analyticity of $f$". So it seems to claim that we satisfy the same condition above in the $z$-plane but I do not understand how this is case. I tried to show this but I was unable to do so. But they arrive at the right answer by doing this.

I am unfortunately unable to send a link to the lecture notes but I have added a [link to a paper](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0550321373903751/1-s2.0-0550321373903751-main.pdf?_tid=16e58448-c066-4daf-b1b0-5861c7237e66&acdnat=1540213089_5111d5b9f252ea140fece230714b9dbf) that makes same claim.(on page 3, last paragraph they seem to explicitly suggest that it does)

I apologise if this is a very basic question but I'm an experimental physicist so I have never studied these things in great depth as it doesn't have much to do with my day to day tasks. Any help/advice is appreciated.

Comment: Dear Alex Francisco, if you look at the paper I linked, then on page 3, last paragraph they seem to explicitly suggest that it does.

Comment: No $\beta$ is chosen to be real. I can send you the paper if you want

Comment: No matter whether the final one acts on $f$ or on its domain, real analyticity will be lost unless $f=0$.

Comment: Dear Alex Francisco, is there any other condition that $f$ might satisfy that would make it real analytic in final mapping besides it being 0 everywhere.

Comment: The other condition is that $β=0$, which is also degenerate.

Comment: "we start with a function $f$ that is supposed to be real analytic so satisfies the condition
$$f(\bar{s}) = \overline{f(s)}$$" I do not understand this.

Comment: Dear zhw, which part is not clear? I am just given a function $f$ that I know for a fact must satisfy that condition, function acting on the complex conjugate is just the complex conjugate of the function. I am wondering whether this function still has this property when its composed with all those other conformal maps.

Comment: OK, but that property has nothing to do with real analyticity. By definition, a function is real analytic on $\mathbb R^2$ iff it is locally representable by power series in $x$ and $y,$ where  $s\in \mathbb C$ is $s=x+iy.$

Comment: Do you see that the conjugation property has little to do with being real analytic?

Comment: I think I do. But this has now really confused me entirely. Because the functions I'm referring to are the Feynman amplitudes which are required to be (complex) analytic in quantum field theory but now I don't know why above the paper I've referenced is talking about real analyticity because the property of interest is the conjugation relation and how what happens to it when we conformally map the real line to the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\i{\mathrm{i}}\def\e{\mathrm{e}}$Note that if $g$ and $h$ are both real-analytic, then so is $g \circ h$ since$$
(g \circ h)(\overline{z}) = g(h(\overline{z})) = g(\overline{h(z)}) = \overline{g(h(z))} = \overline{(g \circ h)(z)}. \quad \forall z \in \mathbb{C}
$$
Now it suffices to verify that if $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ad - bc ≠ 0$, then$$
g_1(z) = \frac{az + b}{cz + d},\ g_2(z) = z^2,\ g_3(z) = \sqrt{z}
$$
are all real-analytic. For any $z = r\e^{\i θ}\in \mathbb{C}\ (r > 0,\ θ \in (-π, π])$,\begin{gather*}
g_1(\overline{z}) = \frac{a\overline{z} + b}{c\overline{z} + d} = \frac{\overline{az + b}}{\overline{cz + d}} = \overline{\left( \frac{az + b}{cz + d} \right)} = \overline{g_1(z)},\\
g_2(\overline{z}) = \overline{z}^2 = \overline{z^2} = \overline{g_2(z)},\\
g_3(\overline{z}) = g_4(r\e^{-\i θ}) = \sqrt{r} \e^{-\i \frac{θ}{2}} = \overline{\sqrt{r} \e^{\i \frac{θ}{2}}} = \overline{g_4(z)}.
\end{gather*}
Therefore, $g_1, g_2, g_3$ are all real-analytic.

Comment: You write "if $g$ and $h$ are both real-analytic, then so is $g \circ h$ "  That is true, but it has nothing to do with the conjugation property.